# How to set tab to 4 spaces in vim?

Tags: linux, unix

By default, the tab in vim is set to 8 spaces. How can we set the tab to 4 spaces in vim permanently?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Create a `~/.vimrc` file with this line:

```
set ts=4 sw=4
```

This will set tabstops every 4 spaces and set the shiftwidth (that amount you indent) as 4 spaces also to match your tabstops.

Answer (score 19):

Make `~/.vimrc` and add this:

```
set tabstop=4
```

Here are some other helpful ones:

```
syntax on " Syntax highlighting
set showmatch " Shows matching brackets
set ruler " Always shows location in file (line#)
set smarttab " Autotabs for certain code
set shiftwidth=4
```

Comment: my backspace is not working after doing this.

Comment: @shahooo add `runtime defaults.vim` to the top of your `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just using vi (some people do not have vim available) put this in your .exrc file in your home directory or where you are editing code if you have/want a specific startup for a particular directory of code:

set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set expandtab "this might not work on all hosts"
"quotes make nice comments in your .exrc files"